# How to get view to work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on this view. I am trying to add a view called StoreSales_vw in the Pubs database that shows the store name from all stores in California that match this criteria in the sales table: sales with quantities greater than 20 payterms greater than 'Net 30'. THis is what I have so far:

```
CREATE VIEW StoreSales_vw
AS
SELECT  dbo.stores.state,
            dbo.sales.qty,
           dbo.sales.payterms
FROM   dbo.sales 
INNER JOIN
         dbo.stores ON dbo.sales.stor_id = dbo.stores.stor_id
Where state ='California' quantites >20,payterm > 'Net 30'
```

I am getting an error on the StoreSales_vw and then by the quantities. Im not to sure how to do the last part when it is asking to do the city = california and the payterm, and quantities. I can usually do it if it is one but its asking for three things. Now would I put in more joins. Can someone explain this a little bit to me I am still new at it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to split your `WHERE` conditions up with `AND`

```
Where state ='California'
AND quantites >20
AND payterm > 'Net 30'
```

Comment: Thanks that what I was woundering if you could actually do that I didnt know for sure.